# Send about ten two digit numbers at a time to a Bluetooth device at random intervals

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building a BLE remote controller application.

I am paring a BLE device with the Android phone with the tested and working code below.

```
Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();
intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);
```

I want to connect to one of the devices in the paired list, and I know the name, which is always the same.

Later, I want to send about ten two digit numbers at a time to that device at random intervals (from a listener for a button), and I don't need any information back.  Simplex communication only, Android phone to BLE device.

Comment: That code does nothing but open up settings. It doesn't pair or send data.

Comment: What do you have that comes from here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html or maybe here? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: Re the code, on my phone, it opens up a premade Android activity which shows available devices, I tap the device I want to pair, then it moves up to the list of Paired Devices.  Now I want to in another activity tap a button, and via a listener select the device which will match the name I want to connect to in the paired list, and then send some data to it.

Comment: Read the linked tutorials and try programming something  yourself. Then post a _specific_ programming question

Comment: "it opens up a premade Android activity" -- Yes, the same thing you get from  going to Settings > Bluetooth *manually*.

Comment: Read the links I posted. The second of which allows you to *programmatically* pair and connect to any Bluetooth device

Comment: Yes, I am calling the Settings > Bluetooth activity from my app, I think it is easier for the user than to have them go somewhere else to pair, and then back to mine.  Later with java in my App, I want to connect to the BLE device which always has the same name for every user, and then send some one way only data to it.  Then maybe a day later if the user wants to change some config info for the BLE device, have the java connect to the same name, and send some more data.

Comment: Sorry, it's late here, got to give this a rest, but I need to programmatically  connect only since it has been manually paired in the Settings > Bluetooth.

Comment: I am sorry but I am missing something, the question has been down voted if that is the correct expression, because it does not show any research effort.  Where do I show my research effort? I have struggled through Gettting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy (O'REILLY), tried to get a lot of code working from GitHub, many examples have depreciated code.  Many hours at my favorite search engine looking for answers, as I am not an expert at this.  This forum should be about fact, not opinion, and just because it is your opinion that I am lazy, does not make it a fact.  Email me, ve7xet@telus.net

Comment: No-one is saying you are lazy. What you are missing is that StackOverflow is not a magic box where you can post your requirements and someone else writes the code which you can quickly copy and paste into your project. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) The tutorial that was linked in the comments has something very close to what you want. Read it, then try and adapt it to your situation. If you get stuck, post a specific question. If you are just hoping for a copy-paste for your exact requirement, then hire a programmer to do it for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I never said it was a magic box, but there is such a thing as reusable code.  Unrelated, but I have helped Zilog develop a subroutine for SPI communication which they hand out to anybody who does not want to bit-bang and use a proper SPI routine, and I have uncovered a serious issue with the data sheet (which they corrected) for the ADXL345 from Analog Devices which could very expensive mistakes for a hardware designer.

Comment: I have a friend who is an published author on Java, Android development etc. he has done some Bluetooth work in the past, and is interested in getting into BLE, he said we could work together if I wish on this topic.  I am sure that we can create some reusable code for this.  I started writing reusable assembly language code for embedded controllers in the 1980's, long before it became a popular expression.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, but it is amazing what a good night's sleep can do.  Assuming that I want to connect to a BLE device with a DEVICE_NAME of "Red Racer', the following plug in code will make the correct connection.  Darn too many characters, I will have to send it as a separate file, have not done that yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
                @Override
                public void uiDeviceFound(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] record )
                {
                    String msg                                                                      ;
                    String deviceName = device.getName()                                            ;
                    String redRacer   = "Red Racer"                                                 ;
                    if (redRacer.equals(deviceName))
                    {
                        boolean status                                                              ;
                        status = mBleWrapper.connect(device.getAddress().toString())                ;
                        if (status == false)
                        {
                            msg = "Sorry, could not connect to Red Racer"                           ;
                            Toast.makeText(SecondaryActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()    ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            msg = "Connected to Red Racer"                                          ;
                            Toast.makeText(SecondaryActivity.this,msg + "   " + deviceName + "   " + redRacer,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()    ;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

During my research to resolve the issue I found this brief, but informative article on the differences between pairing and bonding as far as BLE is concerned:

https://piratecomm.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/ble-pairing-vs-bonding/

Giving credit where credit is due. The above code which resolved my issue was taken from Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy (O'REILLY), although the code copied directly from their book continually crashed the activity whenever it was called.  After correcting the problems, as per the above code, it works flawlessly.  Now that the connection is made, I have to push my control code out the established link to the Simblee chip on my slave board.

Overall the code is what I would define as plug-in reusable code which I think will be applicable to others who might want the same functionality.  I will post the complete code, once I have it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my own question which was, is there any copy an paste code to implement a simple open loop control system with BLE, with the phone being the master which sends control codes to a BLE slave which can control several real world devices, like motors, lights, heaters, etc.

First of all, I realize an open loop control system is the least desirable control system there is, but in my case the Simblee RFD77101 does not have a characteristic which will return the value written to it, so a closed loop control system is not possible.

Eventually I would like to embellish this code to include read capabilities, etc. but that is not a current priority for me.

Finally, I am a complete newbie at Android/Java development, so if you have any comments or questions, please be nice, and I will do what I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
        package com.my_android_app.my_android_app;

import android.app.Activity                             ;
import android.content.Intent                           ;
import android.content.SharedPreferences                ;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager                ;
import android.os.Bundle                                ;
import android.os.Handler                               ;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity         ;
import android.util.Log                                 ;
import android.view.Gravity                             ;
import android.view.View                                ;
import android.widget.Button                            ;
import android.widget.TextView                          ;
import android.widget.Toast                             ;

import java.util.List                                   ;
import java.util.UUID                                   ;
import java.util.Calendar                               ;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter               ;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice                ;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt                  ;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic    ;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService           ;

public class BLE_Test_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public  BLE_Test_Activity.mSensorState mState               ;
    private enum mSensorState {IDLE, ACC_ENABLE, ACC_READ}      ;
    boolean connectedTo                     = false             ;
    boolean okButtonClicked                 = false             ;
    boolean receivedRSSI                    = false             ;
    private byte[] mRawValue                = null              ;
    private int mIntValue                   = 0                 ;
    private String mAsciiValue              = ""                ;
    private String mStrValue                = ""                ;
    private String mLastUpdateTime          = ""                ;
    private boolean mNotificationEnabled    = false             ;
    private final String LOGTAG             = "BLETEST"         ;
    private final String TARGET_BLE         = "My BLE Device"   ;
    private String gattList                 = ""                ;
    private int rssi_1                      = 0                 ;
    private int rssi_2                      = 0                 ;
    private int rssi_3                      = 0                 ;
    private int rssi_4                      = 0                 ;
    private int valueRSSI                   = 0                 ;
    private String mDeviceRSSI                                  ;
    private TextView mDeviceStatus                              ;
    private TextView mDeviceRssiView                            ;
    private String mDeviceAddress                               ;
    private static final long SCANNING_TIMEOUT = 5 * 1000; /* 5 seconds */
    // The UUID variable values below are only applicable to the RFD77101 BLE chip.
    // Enter values here which are applicable to the BLE device you are using.
    private static final UUID
        UUID_SIMBLEE_SERVICE          = UUID.fromString("0000fe84-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb") ,
        UUID_SIMBLEE_CHARACTERISTIC_2 = UUID.fromString("2d30c083-f39f-4ce6-923f-3484ea480596") ;
    private boolean mScanning = false                           ;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler()                    ;
    private BleWrapper mBleWrapper = null                       ;   // Add this line to instantiate the BLE wrapper
    private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCharacteristic = null  ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)                                                          ;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble__test_)                                                ;
    connectViewsVariables()                                                                     ;
    final String dataSentMessage    = "Your " + TARGET_BLE + " put your transmitted message here."    ;

    mBleWrapper = new BleWrapper(this, new BleWrapperUiCallbacks.Null() {
        @Override
        public void uiDeviceFound(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] record) {
        if (TARGET_BLE.equals(device.getName())) {
            if (mBleWrapper.connect(device.getAddress())) {
//                        Toast.makeText(BLE_Test_Activity.this, device.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // This is included for debugging purposes
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(BLE_Test_Activity.this, "Sorry, could not connect to " + TARGET_BLE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        }  // ********************** uiDeviceFound *************************************

        public void uiDeviceConnected(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothDevice device) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            mDeviceStatus.setText   ("connected ")      ;
            mDeviceRssiView.setText ("measuring .")     ;
            connectedTo = true;
            }
        });
        }  // ********************** uiDeviceConnected *************************************

        public void uiDeviceDisconnected(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothDevice device)  // Takes about 20 seconds to display disconnected,
        {                                                                                         // then more than thirty minutes to reconnect.
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            mDeviceStatus.setText  ("disconnected")     ;
            mDeviceRssiView.setText("disconnected")     ;
            connectedTo = false;
            }
        });
        }  // ********************** uiDeviceDisconnected *************************************

        @Override
        public void uiCharacteristicForService(    BluetoothGatt gatt,
                               BluetoothDevice device,
                               BluetoothGattService service,
                               List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> chars)
        {
        super.uiCharacteristicForService(gatt, device, service, chars);
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic c : chars)
        {
            String charName = BleNamesResolver.resolveCharacteristicName(c.getUuid().toString())    ;
            gattList += "Characteristic: " + charName + "\n"                                        ;
        }
        }  // ********************** uiCharacteristicForService *************************************

        public void uiNewRssiAvailable(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            if (rssi_4 == 0)
            {
                mDeviceRSSI = "measuring ....."         ;
                mDeviceRssiView.setText(mDeviceRSSI)    ;
            }
            if (rssi_3 == 0)
            {
                mDeviceRSSI = "measuring ...."          ;
                mDeviceRssiView.setText(mDeviceRSSI)    ;
            }
            if (rssi_2 == 0)
            {
                mDeviceRSSI = "measuring ..."           ;
                mDeviceRssiView.setText(mDeviceRSSI)    ;
            }
            if (rssi_1 == 0)
            {
                mDeviceRSSI = "measuring .."            ;
                mDeviceRssiView.setText(mDeviceRSSI)    ;
            }
            rssi_4 = rssi_3     ;
            rssi_3 = rssi_2     ;
            rssi_2 = rssi_1     ;
            rssi_1 = rssi       ;
            if (rssi_4 != 0) {
                valueRSSI = (rssi_1 + rssi_2 + rssi_3 + rssi_4) / 4 ; // This is a simple moving average to filter out noise
                mDeviceRSSI = (valueRSSI) + " dBm"                  ;
                mDeviceRssiView.setText(mDeviceRSSI)                ;
            }
            receivedRSSI = true                                     ;
            }
        })                                                              ;

        if (okButtonClicked)
        {
            okButtonClicked = false                             ;

            // Build up newValue with the data you want to send out the BLE link.
            // I have hard coded 0202 just for testing purposes.
            // Make sure the contents of newValue is Hex only 0 - 9, A - F
            String newValue =  "0202"                                                                                   ; 
            byte[] dataToWrite = parseHexStringToBytes(newValue)                                                        ;
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic mCharacteristic                                                                 ;
            mCharacteristic = gatt.getService(UUID_SIMBLEE_SERVICE).getCharacteristic(UUID_SIMBLEE_CHARACTERISTIC_2)    ;
            mBleWrapper.writeDataToCharacteristic(mCharacteristic, dataToWrite)                                         ;
        }
        }  // *************************** uiNewRssiAvailable ***********************************************

        @Override
        public void uiNewValueForCharacteristic(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                            BluetoothDevice device,
                            BluetoothGattService service,
                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch,
                            String strValue,
                            int intValue,
                            byte[] rawValue,
                            String timestamp)
        {
        super.uiNewValueForCharacteristic(gatt, device, service, ch, strValue, intValue, rawValue, timestamp);
        for (byte b:rawValue)
        {
            Log.d(LOGTAG,"Val: + b") ;
        }
        }  // ********************** uiNewValueForCharacteristic *************************************

        @Override
        public void uiGotNotification(  BluetoothGatt gatt,
                        BluetoothDevice device,
                        BluetoothGattService service,
                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
        {
        super.uiGotNotification(gatt, device, service, characteristic)                              ;
        String ch = BleNamesResolver.resolveCharacteristicName(characteristic.getUuid().toString()) ;
        Log.d(LOGTAG,"uiGotNotification: " + ch)                                                    ;
        }  // *************************** uiNewValueForCharacteristic *************************************

    } ) ;  // *************************** new BleWrapper **************************************************

    if (!mBleWrapper.checkBleHardwareAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No BluetoothLE compatible hardware detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  ;
        finish()                                                                                        ;
    }  // ********************** checkBleHardwareAvailable *************************************

    Button activity6Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);    // Green check mark button
    activity6Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        if  (connectedTo)
        {
            okButtonClicked = true                                                                          ;
            if (receivedRSSI)
            {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(BLE_Test_Activity.this, dataSentMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)   ;
            TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message)                  ;
            if (v != null) v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)                                                 ;
            toast.show()                                                                                ;
            receivedRSSI = false                                                                        ;
            }
        }
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("saveUserSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit()      ;
        editor.putString("AppIsOn", "yes")                  ;
        editor.apply()                                      ;
        }
    }) ;  // ********************** green check mark *************************************

    Button activity7Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);    // Blue back arrow
    activity7Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)                                                 ;   // Page 60 Sams
        finish()                                                                            ;
        }
    }) ;   // ********************** back arrow *************************************


    }   // ********************************** onCreate ********************************************

    public byte[] parseHexStringToBytes(final String hex) {
    String tmp = hex.substring(2).replaceAll("[^[0-9][a-f]]", "")       ;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[tmp.length() / 2]                           ; // every two letters in the string are one byte finally
    String part = ""                                                    ;
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        part = "0x" + tmp.substring(i*2, i*2+2)                         ;
        bytes[i] = Long.decode(part).byteValue()                        ;
    }
    return bytes                                                        ;
    }  // ********************** parseHexStringToBytes *************************************

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!mBleWrapper.isBtEnabled())     // Check for Bluetooth enabled on each resume
    {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)                                                  ;
        startActivity(enableBtIntent)                                                                                               ;
        Toast.makeText(BLE_Test_Activity.this, "Sorry but BluetoothLE is not supported on your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()   ;
        finish()                                                                                                                    ;
    }
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
        Toast.makeText(BLE_Test_Activity.this, "mBleWrapper.isBtEnabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()                                ;
        finish()                                                                                                                    ;
        return                                                                                                                      ;
    }
    connectedTo = false                                 ;
    mBleWrapper.initialize()                            ;
    mDeviceStatus.setText  ("searching ...")            ;
    mDeviceRssiView.setText("searching ...")            ;
    mBleWrapper.startScanning()                         ;
    }  // ************************************ onResume **********************************************

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    }   // *********************************** onStart *******************************

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    connectedTo = false                                                                 ;
    super.onPause()                                                                     ;
    mBleWrapper.stopScanning()                                                          ;
    mBleWrapper.diconnect()                                                             ;
    mBleWrapper.close()                                                                 ;
    }  // ********************** onPause *************************************

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("saveUserSettings", MODE_PRIVATE)    ;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit()                                      ;
    editor.putString("AppIsOn", "no")                                                   ;
    editor.apply()                                                                      ;
    mBleWrapper.stopScanning()                                                          ;
    mBleWrapper.diconnect()                                                             ;
    mBleWrapper.close()                                                                 ;
    super.onStop()                                                                      ;
    }  // ********************** onStop *************************************

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("saveUserSettings", MODE_PRIVATE)    ;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit()                                      ;
    editor.putString("AppIsOn", "no")                                                   ;
    editor.apply()                                                                      ;
    mBleWrapper.stopScanning()                                                          ;
    mBleWrapper.diconnect()                                                             ;
    mBleWrapper.close()                                                                 ;
    super.onDestroy()                                                                   ;
    }  // ********************** onDestroy *************************************

    private void connectViewsVariables() {
    mDeviceStatus   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.peripheral_status)                   ;
    mDeviceRssiView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.peripheral_rssi)                     ;
    }   // ********************** connectViewsVariables ********************************
}       // ***************************** BLE_Test_Activity *****************************
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ble_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context="com.my_android_app.my_android_app.BLE_Test_Activity">

    <TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/peripheral_status"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button39" />

    <TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/peripheral_rssi"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView20" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:background="@drawable/returnicon"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button39"
    android:layout_marginStart="46dp" />

    <Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:background="@drawable/checkmark"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button39"
    android:layout_marginEnd="44dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resources used by this demo.

- https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/developer-resources-tools/app-acc-2 Download the Bluetooth Application Accelerator kit here, it contains several classes you will need to make this demo work, along with working Java code you can use in you app.
  The BLE Demo app included in this kit is formatted for Android Studio thankfully.  The BLE Demo app is excellent.  In addition to being built around the BLE wrapper which is part of the the Applicaton Accelerator, the BLE Demo drills down into your BLE devices and displays all parameters and their values.  The value of this can not be underestimated because in my case, the manufacturer of the BLE device I am using did not even document the UUIDs for the services and characteristics I needed to write to.
- https://github.com/microbuilder/IntroToBLE  Here is the source code from the excellent book 'Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy', O'REILLY.  If all you want to do is read and write to a BLE device, this book contains far to much information, especially the marketing information for BLE, however the tutorial for Android development is excellent.  Be aware that there are mistakes in the sample code in the book, and the sample code is not the same, but is similar as per this download.
- https://evothings.com/2.1/doc/tutorials/how-to-connect-to-ble-devices.html This is an excellent tutorial on connecting with a BLE device with JavaScript which is useless of course for a Java program, however the connection methodology is the same.  Also this tutorial explains in simple terms the sequence of events which are required to connect to a BLE device.
- https://piratecomm.wordpress.com/category/bluetooth-le Here is a brief, but excellent article on Pairing and Bonding, relative to BLE devices.

Usage instructions:

1. Install the BLE Demo app from the Bluetooth application accelerator onto your Android phone.
2. Copy several classes from the BLE Demo app and put them into your app.
       These classes are: BleWrapper, BleNamesResolver, BleDefinedUUIDs, BleWrapperUiCallbacks and FetchAddressIntentService.
3. Create a new empty activity in your app which you will use to place switches, seek bars etc. whose values you wish to send out the BLE link.
4. Copy and paste the BLE_JAVA into the class created by the new activity you just created.
       Replace every occurrence of my_android_app with whatever is applicable for your app. 
       Replace every occurrence of BLE_Test_Activity with whatever is applicable for your activity.
       For the string private final String TARGET_BLE = "My BLE Device" , put the device name of your target device at "My BLE Device" .
       In the section private static final UUID, you will need to enter the UUID values applicable to your device. You can use the BLE Demo app to find them if you do not know what they are.
5. Copy and paste the BLE_XML into the XML file which was just created, and replace every occurrence of my_android_app with whatever is applicable for your app. 
       Replace every occurrence of BLE_Test_Activity with whatever is applicable for your activity.
6. I have included a stripped down version of my manifest for an example which I feel has the necessary ingredients for the BLE implementation.
7. Now you can put the switches, seek bars, etc. into the new activity you just created, and put the values of those controls in the string, 'newValue' which will be the data which will be sent out via BLE.

   I hope I have included all necessary steps, if not please let me know so that I can make the applicable changes.